# I am performing kMeans clustering to age and gender but i am getting the following error " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'"

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

Attaching my code below

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

#Reading the dataset 
age = data['Age']
gender = data['Gender'].replace({'Male':1,'Female': 0})


d1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([gender,age]))
#Fetching the required columns  
print(x)
imp = SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")
imp.fit_transform(d1)
#Applying KMeans 

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 2, random_state = 0) 
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(x) 

#Visualising the clusters 
plt.scatter(x[y_kmeans == 0, 0], x[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 20, c = 'red', label ='Cluster 1') 
plt.scatter(x[y_kmeans == 1, 0], x[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 20, c = 'blue', label ='Cluster 2') 
plt.scatter(x[y_kmeans == 2, 0], x[y_kmeans == 2, 1],s = 20, c = 'green', label ='Cluster 3') 

#Plotting the centroids 
plt.scatter(kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 0], kmeans.cluster_centers_[:, 1],s = 30, c = 'yellow', label = 'Centroids') 

plt.title('Clusters of datapoints') 
plt.xlabel('Age') 
plt.ylabel('Gender') 
plt.legend() 
plt.show()
```

Though i tried handling NaN values.I just wanted to cluster age and gender using kmeans and i only know basic python program only

Comment: Could you share the code you used to remove/replace `NaN` /missing values? This error is often raised when you're trying to call `split` on a string that is a `None`. If the count of `NaN` values is not significant you can consider using `dropna`  here.

Comment: I don't see your actual data, but everything looks ok. You can handle NANs like this.

df = df.fillna(0)